# Flask to uwsgi threading get stuck

Tags: python, uwsgi, flask

im Using Python 3.7.3, uwsgi 2.0.18, (docker container image python:3-stretch)

We have development environment where we are running our code on flask and we change it to uwsgi when we test it on production.
Im running a py script which get live-stream pcm audio from redis (another container)

Now, when we run it on flask all works fine! when we run it on uwsgi threads gets stuck and die.

uwsgi settings :

```
[uwsgi]
http =  :5000
socket = :3031
wsgi-env-behaviour=holy
master=1
uid=1000
gid=2000
master=1
processes = 1
threads = 1
protocol = uwsgi
wsgi-file = server.py
chdir = /app/base/
callable = app
http-raw-body
single-interpreter
paste-logger = true
honour-stdin
#logto = /tmp/errlog
vacuum = true
harakiri-verbose = true
harakiri = 60
cpu-affinity =3
http-timeout = 60
optimize = 2
http-keepalive
listen=30
workers = 40
ugreen
reaper
start_response-nodelay
greenlet
```

logs :

```
HARAKIRI: -- wchan> 0
Wed Jun  5 15:55:48 2019 - HARAKIRI !!! worker 24 status !!!
Wed Jun  5 15:55:48 2019 - HARAKIRI [core 0] XX.XX.XX.XX- GET /pcm_json since 1559750087
Wed Jun  5 15:55:48 2019 - HARAKIRI !!! end of worker 24 status !!!
Wed Jun  5 15:55:48 2019 - *** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 27 (pid: 32, try: 1) ***

DAMN ! worker 10 (pid: 15) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 10 (new pid: 64)
```

whats the major difference between flask and uwsgi regarding post and get requests ?

After googlins 2 days in a row no matter how much i have changed the settings nothing helps, i have tried all things suggested.

we are considering moving to gunicorn..
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

this is the code sendind request  :

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(server, port)
 headers = { "ID": ID, "debugLevel": 1, "Multipart": 1, "Audio": 1, "Accept": "application/json" } conn.request("GET", "/pcm", "", headers)
 ret = conn.getresponse()
```

this is another error i see in cli

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function get_pcm>
```

Comment: Could you include an example request?

Comment: You should look at where in your code do your threads get stuck?

Comment: @LucasRamage the request in the code looks like this : 
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(server, port)
    headers = {
        "ID": ID,
        "debugLevel": 1,
        "Multipart": 1,
        "Audio": 1,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }                                                                                    
    conn.request("GET", "/pcm", "", headers)
    ret = conn.getresponse()

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes but in flask it does not happens.  only in uwsgi thats why i want to know the diff between flask and uwsgi. if you have a suggestion on how to see where it is stuck please let me know (im new to python)

Comment: @BatchenRegev, I meant the actual request/response, like in postman or a proxy tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i figured what made the uwsgi workers crash :

```
" harakiri = 60"
```

in my uwsgi.ini conf , because our workers connection is for long time ( giving livestream) i guess harakiri thought it was overload or taking to much time so after 60 sec it would crash it.

for our server - multi-connection and livestream this settings works :

```
[uwsgi]
http =  :5000
socket = :3031
wsgi-env-behaviour=holy
master=1
uid=1000
gid=2000
master=1
threads = 4
protocol = uwsgi
wsgi-file = machine.py
chdir = /app
callable = app
http-raw-body
single-interpreter
paste-logger = true
honour-stdin
cpu-affinity =3
http-timeout = 60
optimize = 2
http-keepalive
listen=30
workers = 80
ugreen
reaper
start_response-nodelay
greenlet
offload-threads = 10
```